# PHP - I want to know how to get function trace

Tags: php, backtrace

Is there any way to know all previous functions were called before a point in my code?
For example: I set a point in abc.php in my project, and I want to get all functions that were called before that point was reached. debug_backtrace() does not help here.
Thanks so much :)

Comment: Can you explain why `debug_backtrace()` doesn't help you?

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig, imagine the code `a(); b(); c();`. When `c()` is called, he wants to see that `a()` and `b()` were called at some point. `debug_backtrace()` won't show that.

Comment: Can you explain why none of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=function+trace+php answered your question already?

Answer (score 2):

xdebug can generate function traces for you. See: http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace

Answer (score 1):

use [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) it will show trace and much more useful info

Answer (score 0):

Use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) for trace and [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) for vizualization this one.