# PHP - How can I see all the actions that a class performs?

Tags: php, debugging, trace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - I want to know how to get function trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758486/php-i-want-to-know-how-to-get-function-trace)

I need to see what a php script does when I call it.

I'm calling a script like:

```
php -f thescript.php --option1 --option2
```

The code is something like this:

```
class thescript {

    static function func01($some_parameter) {
        //some code here
    }

    static function func02($some_parameter) {
        //some code here
    }

    static function func03($some_parameter) {
        //some code here
    }

}

function helperFunction01($some_parameter)
{
    //some code here
}
```

How can I trace all the functions and methods that the call travels?

Best Regards,

Comment: There's no obvious easy way to do this - `debug_backtrace` gives you what you need but you would need to place it inside your code. What do you need this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could execute a [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to see through which calls you end up somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use xdebug to do this http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace